# optimal control to minimise a path

Tags: optimization, control-theory, hamilton-equations

[image]

I'm having issues solving this problem. Here is what I have tried so far.

$$ u=\dot {x_1}   + x_1 $$
$$ J= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t_1}((2x_1)^2+2\dot {x_1} x_1 + \dot {(x_1)^2})dt$$

Can I proceed and say 
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1})-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot {x_1}}=0 $$
or would this be incorrect because I don't have $t_1$?
I also think Pontryagin might help here but I'm not sure how to proceed if that's the case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried when using Pontryagin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling

$$
H(x,u,\lambda) = \frac{1}{2} \left(u(t)^2+x(t)^2\right)+\lambda (t) (u(t)-x(t))
$$

we have

$$
\dot\lambda(t) = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = \lambda(t)+x(t)\\
\frac{\partial H}{\partial u} = \lambda(t) + u(t) = 0
$$

Now solving

$$
\dot\lambda(t) = \lambda(t)+x(t)\\
\lambda(t) + u(t) = 0\\
\dot x(t)+x(t) = u(t)
$$
 we obtain

$$
x(t) = \frac{\left(7 c_1-3 c_2\right) \sinh \left(\sqrt{2} t\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+\left(5 c_1-2 c_2\right) \cosh \left(\sqrt{2} t\right)\\
\lambda(t) = \frac{\left(7 c_2-17 c_1\right) \sinh \left(\sqrt{2} t\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+\left(5 c_2-12 c_1\right) \cosh \left(\sqrt{2} t\right)
$$

Now including the contour conditions $x(0) = 1, x(t_f) = 2$ we obtain

$$
c_1= 2 \sqrt{2} \coth \left(\sqrt{2} t_f\right)-4 \sqrt{2} \text{csch}\left(\sqrt{2} t_f\right)+3\\
c_2= 5\sqrt{2} \coth \left(\sqrt{2} t_f\right)-10 \sqrt{2} \text{csch}\left(\sqrt{2} t_f\right)+7
$$

Now from the conditions

$$
H_{t_f} = 0\\
u(t_f)+\lambda(t_f) = 0
$$

we obtain

$$
\lambda(t_f) = 2\left(-1\pm\sqrt 2\right)
$$

and then follows

$$
t_f = \frac{\ln 2}{\sqrt 2}
$$

etc.

Comment: Have you used Pontryagin for this after maximising the Hamiltonian?

Comment: @RobbieMeaney Yes The hamiltonian is $H(x,u,\lambda)$